# AChartEngine dates on X-axis with BarChart or CubeChart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to make a chart with dates on x-axis and consumption per time month/day etc. on y-axis.

I have database of actual states of energy meters in specific datetime:

- 1.1.2014 - 150 kWh
- 5.1.2014 - 200 kWh

So I can get consumption/time like - 50/5 => 10 kWh/day for time from 1.1. to 5.1.

I guess I need some resolution, for every day for example (better for every hour), and add the value of consumption in every hour from 1.1. to 5.1.. But then I need to have that resolution on x-axis labels, 1,2,3...31 day of month etc. But I want to achieve that on zoom out I would have another resolution, means another labels on x-axis. Months. Like 1,2,3..12 And values of consumption with lower resolution, rounded in specific months.

I really don't know how to do that, if it's even possible?

I would like to achieve X-axis label in zoom (better for hours in higher zoom):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b52B1.png]

And X-axis labels for zoomed out, like on this graph:

[image]

Do I need to make my map of x-axis labels for whole times (where I have data of consumption) and then fill it with counted values somehow?

PS: I want to achieve this X-axis labels with Bar chart or Cubic line (cube) chart.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Instead of writing an 'answer' to bump your question, please *edit it*.

Comment: thanks for answer, you mean edit question to make it more clear or for bumping up? edit: oh i see your answer to my deleted post, thanks for tip